# Forcing a '0' return value when no matching records exist

Tags: sql, ms-access

**Background:**

I have a table in an Access database (let's call it [tblMyTable]). The table has thousands of entries for each month, with each entry belonging to a category, e.g:

```
ID  Month  Category
--  -----  --------
 1      1  White
 2      1  Black
 3      2  White
...etc.
```

**Problem:**

When I run my (somewhat simplified) query

```sql
SELECT tblMyTable.Month, COUNT(tblMyTable.ID) AS CountedIDs 
FROM tblMyTable 
WHERE tblMyTable.Category = "Black" 
GROUP BY tblMyTable.Month
```

the return is:

```
Month  Count
-----  -----
    1      1
```

whereas what I expect/need is:

```
Month  Count
-----  -----
    1      1
    2      0
```

I've tried using the `NZ()` function to force a '0' return, but not having any luck with that either, hence reaching out to everyone here...

If anything is missing or looks weird with the above, please shout out and I'll try to address it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table named [MonthNumbers] like so

```
MonthNumber
-----------
          1
          2
          3
          4
          5
          6
          7
          8
          9
         10
         11
         12
```

and then use the following query (which includes your original query as a subquery):

```sql
SELECT 
    mn.MonthNumber AS Month,
    Nz(gb.CountedIDs, 0) AS CountedIDs
FROM
    MonthNumbers mn
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            tblMyTable.Month, 
            COUNT(tblMyTable.ID) AS CountedIDs 
        FROM tblMyTable 
        WHERE tblMyTable.Category = "Black" 
        GROUP BY tblMyTable.Month
    ) gb
        ON gb.Month = mn.MonthNumber
```

It returns

```
Month  CountedIDs
-----  ----------
    1  1         
    2  0         
    3  0         
    4  0         
    5  0         
    6  0         
    7  0         
    8  0         
    9  0         
   10  0         
   11  0         
   12  0
```